# Prove that order of function certain order and type properties

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Currently reading the Levin book on Entire functions,
Taking my time practicing by trying to prove the following statements, I have wasted a couple of days fighting with these folks:

1. $p_{fg} \le max(p_{f},p_{g})$
2. $p_{f+g} \le max(p_{f},p_{g})$

There are similar statements for the "types" but they should be easily provable, based on statements for the "order".

3. $\sigma_{fg} \le \sigma_{f}+\sigma_{g})$ <- Provable by logarithm properties.
4. $\sigma_{f+g} \le max(\sigma_{f},\sigma_{g})$ <- proof should be based on proved 2nd stmnt.

Kindly ask for a hint and (if possible) full proof of $$p_{fg} <= max(p_{f},p_{g})$$ and $$p_{f+g} \le max(p_{f},p_{g})$$

I am very confused about these statements.
The second statement will make sense(when at least one order(e.g. (both) is infinite, or one(both) of the orders is equal to zero)

Definition of the order
$$
p = \left[ \limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{log(log(M_f(r)))}{log(r)} \right]
$$

Limits comparison will bring the need to compare the actual different parts of order definition.

For 1st: $$log(M_{f}(r))+log(M_{g}(r)) \le max(log(M_{f}(r)), log(M_{g}(r))$$
For 2nd: $$log(M_{f}(r)+M_{g}(r)) \le max(log(M_{f}(r), log(M_{g}(r))$$

How to prove it for any order? Should I try to do that in the Taylor series?

It is not my homework.

Comment: $M_{fg}(r) \le M_f(r)M_g(r)$ and $M_{f+g}(r) \le M_f(r)+M_g(r) $ which are obvious (first by definition since $M_{fg}(r)=|fg(z_r)|$ for some $|z_r|=r$ but by defintion $|f(z_r)| \le M_f(r), |g(z_r)| \le M_g(r)$ and second by the triangle inequality) imply the result immediately

Comment: Maybe it is a stupid question, but how and why we are ignoring the $max$?
Arent those inequalities implying the same as (e.g.) $(a+b)<= max(a,b)$ and  $(a*b)<= max(a,b)$ ?

Comment: By definition and continuity there is a $|z_r|=r$ which realizes the maximum for $fg$ so $M_{fg}(r)=fg(z_r)$ But also by definition we have $|f(z_r)| \le M_f(r)$ since of course the maximum for $f$ there may be realized by another $w_r$ of modulus $r$; same for $g$ and then for $f+g$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I still not getting it. To begin with, let's focus on the 1st $p_{fg}$
We can rewrite the whole expression like that, $M_fg(r) \le max(M_f(r), M_g(r))$.
What I am not able to get, is how we are proving that  $M_{fg}(r) \le M_f(r)$ OR $M_{fg}(r) \le M_g(r)$ is true, which is implied by $max(a,b)$ function, which returns the larger value. Since, we do not know anything about functions, and we are operating with modules only.

Comment: If we rewrite, (e.g take f to compare with) $M_{fg}(r) \le M_f(r)$ as $M_f(r)*M_g(r) \le M_f(r)$ and divide both parts by $M_f(r)$ We will get $M_g(r) \le 1$, which is true in reality. (e.g: if we take (e.g) $5*0.1 \le max(5,1)$)

Comment: We get $M_{fg} \le M_f(r)M_g(r)$ which essentially implies that $M_{fg}\le \max (M_f^2,M_g^2)$ so when you take $\log \log$ you get $\max(\log \log M_f, \log \log M_g)+\log \log 2$ etc

Comment: It's $\log 2$ above but that of course is irrelevant when you divide by $\log r$ as the ratio of constant to $\log r$ goes to zero

Comment: @Conrad 
Oh, Thank you very much for the explanation! Finally, I get it!
I assume, that for the $p_{fg}$(second), we can use the same trick, since $(M_f)^2$ is quite strong and covers $(f+g)$ as well, without using triangle inequality.
I will write the full answer. Thanks, once again!

Comment: happy to be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Conrad, you have this proof.

Let's prove, **statement 1.** $p_{fg} \le max(p_{f},p_{g})$.

By utilizing the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle), we are having the formulas
$M_{fg} \le M_f(r)*M_g(r)$, as well as $M_{f+g} \le M_f(r)+ M_g(r)$

Those equations are true for $|f|$ and $|g|$.

By definition of the order
$$
p = \left[ \limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{log(log(M_f(r)))}{log(r)} \right]
$$

It is reasonable to consider only the distinct part
(sum -> multiplication by log properties.).
$$loglog(M_{f}(r)*M_{g}(r)) \le max(loglog(M_{f}(r)), loglog(M_{g}(r))$$

$max(log(M_{f}(r)), log(M_{g}(r))$ might be not obvious, so we will consider a much stronger condition.
$$loglog(M_{f}(r)*M_{g}(r)) \le max(loglog(M^2_{f}(r)), loglog(M^2_{g}(r))$$

So, by logarithm properties, we obtain: (for ($loglog(M^2_{f}(r)$)

$$loglog(M^2_{f}(r) = log(2*log(M_{f}(r)) = log(2) + loglog(M_{f}(r))$$

The same applies to $M_g$.
We can write:
$$max(log(2) + loglog(M_{f}(r)),log(2) + loglog(M_{g}(r)))$$

Which equals to:

$$max(loglog(M_{f}(r)),loglog(M_{g}(r))) + log(2)$$

Let us have the final inequality written down:

parameter $ A = \limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{loglog(M_{f}(r))}{log(r)}$

parameter $ B = \limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{loglog(M_{g}(r))}{log(r)}$

$$\limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{loglog(M_{fg}(r))}{log(r} \le max(A,B) + \limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{log(2)}{log(r)}$$

So, $\limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{log(2)}{log(r)}$ is going to be 0 as $log(2)* \frac{1}{\inf} = log(2) * 0 = 0$

Thus, $\Delta$. The statement is proven.

**Statement 2 $p_{f+g} \le max(p_{f},p_{g})$**

Proof is the same, as
$$loglog(M_{f+g}(r)) \le max(loglog(M^2_{f}(r)), loglog(M^2_{g}(r))$$

Since $(a+b) or (a*b) \le max(a^2,b^2)$